# error in Python gradient measurement

Tags: python, scipy

I need to fit a straight line to my data to find out if there is a gradient.

I am currently doing this with scipy.stats.linregress.

I'm a little confused though, because one of the outputs of linregress is the "standard error", but I'm not sure how linregress calculated this, as the uncertainty of your data points is not given as an input.

Surely the uncertainty on the data points influence how uncertain the given gradient is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard error of a linear regression is the standard deviation of the serie obtained by substracting the fitted model to your data points. It indicates how well your data points can be fitted by a linear model.

Comment: Thank you. So the same data points with huge error bars would give a gradient with the same standard error? This seems strange to me, but that's going slightly off-topic I guess.

Comment: @user1551817 A linear regression is not concerned by the way you obtain your data points :-). It can only give you the "best" linear model for this data - best being defined by minimizing the standard error. However, "best" does not mean "good enough", so you also get this error information to check how well the model will perform.

Comment: I see. So is there any similar tool that takes the error bars of your data into account? Thank you.

Comment: You could use a [weighted linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares). However I have never used that, so I am not sure if it really helps.